# res.cookie is not working but Postman shows Cookies

Tags: javascript, json, authentication, cookies

I'm having issues with `res.cookies` not setting cookies from the backend to the frontend on the browser. Additionally, `[req.cookies]` isn't reading cookies from the frontend browser, even if I hardcode the cookies from the frontend. I've tried various solutions, including setting `withCredentials: true`, but it's not sending or reading the cookies as expected. Here's my code:

```js
// 1.)
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import { login_success, login_fail, login_request, clear_errors, signup_request, signup_fail, signup_success, load_user_request, load_user_fail, load_user_success } from "../reducers/userReduces.js";
import { withCookies } from "react-cookie";
// axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export const login = createAsyncThunk("login", async (reqbody, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = reqbody;
        thunkAPI.dispatch(login_request());
        const config = {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            withCredentials: true,
        };

        const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/ecom/v1/login", {
            email,
            password,
            config,
        });

        console.log(data);
        thunkAPI.dispatch(login_success(data));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        thunkAPI.dispatch(login_fail(error));
    }
});

// 2.)
router.route("/login").post(logUser);

exports.logUser = catchAsyncErrors(
    async (req, res, next) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        if (!email || !password) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler("Enter email & password", 400));
        }

        const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");

        if (!user) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid email or password"));
        }

        const ispassword = await user.comparePassword(password);

        if (!ispassword) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid email or password"));
        }

        sendToken(user, 200, res);
        console.log("Sent newcookie request");
    }
);

// 3.)
const sendToken = async (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = await user.jwtToken();

    const options = {
        expiresIn: new Date(
            Date.now() + (process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        ),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "None",
    };

    console.log("Sending token to browser");
    res.cookie("token", token, options);
    console.log("Sent cookie");

    res.status(statusCode).json({
        success: true,
        user,
        token,
    });
};

module.exports = sendToken;

// 4.)
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));
app.use(express.json());


I  did withCredentiales:true and i added origin in cors() and also 
httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "None",
but it wont work
```